# Is there a performance impact on changing color of vector drawables programmatically?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I am using a vector drawable in my code. Based on some condition I need to change the color of the drawable. Using below code to achieve it.

```
Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), 
                        R.drawable.icon_vector_star, null);
    if(drawable != null) {
        drawable = drawable.mutate();
        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        //Change the tint to grey to mark it disabled.
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, 
              ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grey));
        DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    } else {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error while creating vector drawable");
    }
```

Is there a performance impact while doing this? Should I use another vector 
drawable of different color and simply set it? Please suggest.